# Simplifying a matrix expression that involves a Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudoinverse

For $m\geq n$, suppose $L$ is an $m\times n$ real matrix and $P$ is an $m\times m$ diagonal  matrix with nonnegative entries. I did some numerical experimentation to verify that $L'P (PLL'PLL'P)^\dagger PLL'P = (P^{1/2} L)^\dagger P^{1/2}$ where the dagger means the Moore-Penrose inverse. I found the differences are small enough to be rounding errors. I have a proof for the case $P=I$. Is there a formal proof of the general result (and references)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake somewhere and cannot find it yet (will take a look again later) but I think a reasoning like the following can get you the answer :

Note that $(AA^T)^\dagger = (A^T)^\dagger A^\dagger$, we also have the [identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Properties) $A^T=A^\dagger A A^T$ and $A^\dagger=A^T(AA^T)^\dagger$. Let $S=P^{1/2} L$ and $Q=P^{1/2}SS^T$, observe that $S^T=L^T P^{1/2}$ and that $Q^T=SS^T P^{1/2}$, then
\begin{align*}
L^TP (PLL^T PLL^T P)^\dagger PLL^T P &=S^TP^{1/2} (P^{1/2}SS^T SS^T P^{1/2})^\dagger P^{1/2}SS^T P^{1/2}\\
&=S^\dagger SS^T P^{1/2} (P^{1/2}SS^T SS^T P^{1/2})^\dagger P^{1/2}SS^T P^{1/2}\\
&=S^\dagger Q^T (Q Q^T)^\dagger Q P^{1/2}\\
\end{align*}

This is really close to your identity, indeed $Q^T (Q Q^T)^\dagger Q$ is a projection matrix on the span of $Q^T$ which in turns is the span of $S$ and which in turn is the span of $(S^\dagger)^T$ hence $Q^T (Q Q^T)^\dagger Q =(S^\dagger)^T (S^\dagger (S^\dagger)^T)^\dagger S^\dagger$. plugin in we get
\begin{align*}
L^TP (PLL^T PLL^T P)^\dagger PLL^T P &= S^\dagger Q^T (Q Q^T)^\dagger Q P^{1/2}\\
&= S^\dagger (S^\dagger)^T (S^\dagger (S^\dagger)^T)^\dagger S^\dagger P^{1/2}\\
&=S^\dagger P^{1/2}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for looking at this. The only mistake I see is in the last line, where $Q^T (Q Q^T)^\dagger Q$ is $m\times m$ and $S^T (S S^T)^\dagger S$ is $n\times n$ so not equal. On the other hand, if $Q^T (Q Q^T)^\dagger Q = S (S^TS)^\dagger S^T$, the result I am looking for will follow. I think the last equality is true, but how to prove it?

Comment: @user378420 You where right, it allowed me to fix and finish the proof. I don't think that is the best way to phrase it but still I believe it works.

Comment: Sorry, I am lost in "is a projection matrix on the span ... is the span ... is the span hence ...". Is there a formula or a reference for this?

Comment: You can read the definition on the wikipedia page : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Definition
It is a rather good resource for this topic.
$P$ is a projection if $P=P^T$ and $P^2=P$, here it is easy to check. Also two projections on the same space are equal.

Comment: Thanks. Greville (1966) proved $(AB)^\dagger = B^\dagger A^\dagger$ when $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian . So
\begin{align*}
   &
  L'P  \bigl( P LL'P  LL'P \bigr)^\dagger  P LL'P 
    \\ & \quad
  = L'P \bigl( P^{1/2} LL'P \bigr)^\dagger P^{1/2} 
&& \text{As $({m}{m}')^\dagger{m}=({m}')^\dagger$}
    \\ & \quad
  = L'P (P^{1/2})^\dagger \bigl( P^{1/2} LL'P^{1/2} \bigr)^\dagger P^{1/2} 
&& \text{As $P^{1/2} LL'P^{1/2}$ and $P^{1/2}$ are real symmetric}
    \\ & \quad
  = \bigl( P^{1/2} L \bigr)^\dagger P^{1/2} 
&& \text{As ${m}'({m}{m}')^\dagger={m}^\dagger$}
\end{align*}

Comment: The first line don't work right ? what is $m$ ?

Comment: Did I stuff it up? I was thinking
\begin{align*}
   &
  L'P  \bigl( P LL'P  LL'P \bigr)^\dagger  P LL'P 
    \\ & \quad
  = L'P \bigl( P LL'P LL'P \bigr)^\dagger P LL'P^{1/2} P^{1/2} 
    \\ & \quad
  = L'P \bigl( P^{1/2} LL'P \bigr)^\dagger P^{1/2} 
&& \text{Since $({m}{m}')^\dagger{m}=({m}')^\dagger$ with ${m}=P LL'P^{1/2}$}
\end{align*}
Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you are right, it does work, sorry about that.